Извлечение текста из PDF
Пишу чат-бота в Телеграм на Node.js с функционалом:
Юзер присылает PDF-файл, мне нужно текст извлечь оттуда и добавить в гугл-таблицу.
Можно ли извлечь текст из файла, при этом не загрузив его?

Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

нет, файл прийдётся загрузить

Скажите, пожалуйста, в каком месте хранение загруженного файла будет практичнее, бд или другой вариант?
